# Knockout clear binding in views form fields

Tags: knockout.js

After the user has made a post I can't seem to figure out how to clear the values in the form. Is there any type of reset on the knockout bindings? I tried `self.user = null` in the `.done` of the post, but the fields don't clear out of the form fields (view side).

```
function CreateUserModal(userListViewModel) {
    var self = this;

    self.user = userModel;
    self.errors = ko.validation.group(userModel);
    self.userListViewModel = userListViewModel;

    self.save = function () {
        if (self.errors().length == 0) {
            var userJson = ko.mapping.toJS(self.user);
            $.post('/api/user', userJson)
                .done(function () {
                    console.log('POST user.');
                    self.userListViewModel.isCreateModalShown(false);
                    self.user = null;
                    self.userListViewModel.loadData();
                });
        } else {
            console.log(self.errors());
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your HTML markup showing the bindings.

Comment: Added the HTML markup, but I am confused why setting it to null just doesn't clear all the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just setting user to null won't work because user is not an observable. The DOM is updated via observable changes. Update your code as below and it should work for you:

```js
self.user = ko.observable(userModel);
...
// inside done callback
self.user(null);
```